# HOWTO: Sort TableView per column using NSSortDescriptor when column names are unknown?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, nssortdescriptor

I'm loading a CSV file that I know nothing about except that the first row are column headers, which could be anything. The number of columns is unknown too. I tried to add a sortDescriptorPrototype to each column and when I do I get up/down arrows visible in the TableView.

```
    for(NSTableColumn * col in self.tableView.tableColumns){
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: col.title ascending: YES];
    col.sortDescriptorPrototype = sortDescriptor;
}
```

Each time I click on the column sortDescriptorsDidChange is called:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray *)oldDescriptors
    {
        [_data sortUsingDescriptors: [tableView sortDescriptors]];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

_data is a NSMutableArray where data is stored and first row are the header names. Each row is another NSArray Unfortunately I get this error:

```
2017-04-17 12:35:09.979142+0200 Table Tool[20954:2577488] [General] [<__NSCFString 0x610000474840> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key beds.
2017-04-17 12:35:09.982161+0200 Table Tool[20954:2577488] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb31a837b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffc7f9c48d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb31a82c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4c83e5e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 226
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4b55d9c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 283
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4b59aac -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 467
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4b55b79 -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 448
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4b7cc9f _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 371
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fffb4be94f7 -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 468
    9   Table Tool                          0x00000001000051d8 -[Document tableView:sortDescriptorsDidChange:] + 184
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fffb0f05425 -[NSTableView setSortDescriptors:] + 260
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fffb13c9fbc -[NSTableView _changeSortDescriptorsForClickOnColumn:] + 480
```

Obviously I have read a lot on the topic, but all examples assume that you know column names at design-time. I'm interested in a solution with **NSSortDescriptor** and **sortUsingDescriptors** in **Obj-C** or **Swift**, some explanation on sortDescriptorPrototype and why you need it in the first place, since sortDescriptor changes when I click on the column. Is there anything in KVC I can use for the sorting key, like "self" (there is ...valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"...)?

Some useful links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/SortingTableViews/SortingTableViews.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/143828/macos-nstableview-tutorial

Comment: If someone can explain memory management in TableView, that would great. Is the data copied from my _data (NSMutableArray) into TableView? What if you have millions of rows, you don't want to have two copies of the data.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't caused by an unconnected outlet on your storyboard/NIB?

Comment: I'm sure, but I'm new to KVC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely moronic way of solving it that partly works: 
First I extract the column index with this method:

```
-(NSUInteger)getColumnIndexFromTableViewSortDescriptor {
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < _maxColumnNumber; i++){
        if(_tableView.tableColumns[i].title == _tableView.sortDescriptors[0].key){
            return i;
        }
    }
    assert(false && "Missing column name");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I sort the array in-place with sortUsingComparator. Surely this has to be the "wrong". It's completely idiotic to use sortDescriptors if they are not used, other than to figuring out which column was clicked. I guess the click event could figure that out too?

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange: (NSArray *)oldDescriptors
{
    NSUInteger idx = self.getColumnIndexFromTableViewSortDescriptor;
    if(tableView.sortDescriptors[0].ascending){
        [_data sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [[obj2 objectAtIndex:idx] compare:[obj1 objectAtIndex:idx]];
        }];
    } else {
        [_data sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [[obj1 objectAtIndex:idx] compare:[obj2 objectAtIndex:idx]];
        }];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Now the CSV data I'm importing the data in the columns is not uniform, so it could be a NSNumber, followed by three NSDecimalNumber and a few NSString. Partly that's a problem with the data and/or the CSV parser I'm using (ripped from the web, but I will rewrite the sucker later).

So you could end up comparing NSDecimalNumber with NSString which will generate errors like:

`unrecognized selector sent to instance`

So I continued my stupidity with:

```
@interface NSDecimalNumber (CompareString)
-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)string;

@end

@implementation NSDecimalNumber (CompareString)

-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *decimalString = self.stringValue;
    return[decimalString compare:string options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

}
```

Now if you compare two NSDecimalNumber the above will be called and the parameter "string" NSDecimalNumber, even though "string" declared NSString, resulting in "unrecognized selector sent to instance" once again.

Comment: Apparently the block method above is supposed to be faster, any real life performance measurements, you guys?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it/805587